# ¿Cómo agregar una columna pivot con PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

**Tengo un codigo php que genera un excel ahora estoy intentando poner como columna pivot el nombre de esta columna Descripcion_Grupo que forma parte de mi select realmente no se como hacerlo alguien me ayuda por favor este es mi codigo**

```html
// Incluye la biblioteca PhpSpreadsheet
sc_include_library("sys", "phpspreadsheet", "vendor/autoload.php", "include_once = true", "Require = true");


> Crea una instancia de la clase Spreadsheet

$documento = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

// Configura las propiedades del documento
$documento
    ->getProperties()
    ->setCreator("Prueba")
    ->setLastModifiedBy('JuanAquino')
    ->setTitle('Mi primer documento creado con PhpSpreadSheet')
    ->setSubject('El asunto')
    ->setDescription('Este documento fue generado para prueba')
    ->setKeywords('etiquetas o palabras clave separadas por espacios')
    ->setCategory('La categoría');

// Nombre del documento Excel
$nombreDelDocumento = "Mi_primer_archivo.xlsx";



> Configura las cabeceras para la descarga del archivo
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $nombreDelDocumento . '"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Obtiene la hoja de productos por defecto
$hojaDeProductos = $documento->getActiveSheet();
$hojaDeProductos->setTitle("Productos");

// Define el encabezado de los productos
$encabezado = ["Sucursal", "Cod_linea", "Grupo", "Codigo_Sub", "Articulo", "Descripcion_Articulo", "Existencia", "Comprometido", "Inventario", "Diferencia", "Peso_neto", "Peso_unitario", "Peso_Inventario", "Unidades_Inventariadas"];

// Escribe el encabezado en la hoja de productos
$hojaDeProductos->fromArray($encabezado, null, "A1");

// Array para almacenar los totales por sucursal
$totalesPorSucursal = [];
$totalesPorGrupo = [];

// Consulta a la base de datos
$consulta = "SELECT Sucursal, Nombre_Sucursal, Codigo_deposito, Descripcion_deposito, Cod_linea, Descripcion_linea, Grupo, Descripcion_Grupo, Codigo_Sub, Descripcion_sub, Articulo, Descripcion_Articulo, Existencia, Comprometido, Inventario, Diferencia, Peso_neto, Peso_unitario, Peso_Inventario, Unidades_Inventariadas FROM Temporal_stock_Inventario";
sc_select(ds, $consulta);

// Obtiene el conjunto de datos
$productos = {ds};

// Inicializa variables para totales
$totalExistenciaSucursal = 0;
$totalExistenciadeposito = 0;
$totalExistencialinea = 0;
$totalExistenciaGrupo = 0;
$totalExistenciasubgrupo = 0;
$totalExistenciaGeneral = 0;

// Inicializa variables para el control de la sucursal
$subtotalExistenciaSucursal = 0;
$sucursalActual = null;
$nomsucursalActual = null;

$subtotalExistenciadeposito = 0;
$depositoActual = null;
$nomdepositoActual = null;

$subtotalExistencialinea = 0;
$lineaActual = null;
$nomlineaActual = null;

$subtotalExistenciaGrupo = 0;
$GrupoActual = null;
$nomGrupoActual = null;

$subtotalExistenciasubgrupo = 0;
$subGrupoActual = null;
$nomsubGrupoActual = null;

// Comienza en la fila 2 porque la 1 es del encabezado
$numeroDeFila = 2;

$band = 0;

// Itera sobre los productos y escribe en el documento Excel
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    $sucursal = $producto['Sucursal'];
    $nomsucursal = $producto['Nombre_Sucursal'];
    $deposito = $producto['Codigo_deposito'];
    $nomdeposito = $producto['Descripcion_deposito'];
    $linea = $producto['Cod_linea'];
    $nomlinea = $producto['Descripcion_linea'];
    $Grupo = $producto['Grupo'];
    $nomGrupo = $producto['Descripcion_Grupo'];
    $subGrupo = $producto['Codigo_Sub'];
    $nomsubGrupo = $producto['Descripcion_sub'];
    $articulo = $producto['Articulo'];
    $descripcion = $producto['Descripcion_Articulo'];
    $existencia = $producto['Existencia'];
    $comprometido = $producto['Comprometido'];
    $inventario = $producto['Inventario'];
    $diferencia = $producto['Diferencia'];
    $pesoneto = $producto['Peso_neto'];
    $pesounitario = $producto['Peso_unitario'];
    $pesoinventario = $producto['Peso_Inventario'];
    $uninventarioadas = $producto['Unidades_Inventariadas'];

   

    // Actualiza los valores actuales
    $sucursalActual = $sucursal;
    $depositoActual = $deposito;
    $lineaActual = $linea;
    $GrupoActual = $Grupo;
    $subGrupoActual = $subGrupo;

    // Escribe los datos en el documento
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, $sucursal);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $linea);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $numeroDeFila, $Grupo);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $numeroDeFila, $subGrupo);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $numeroDeFila, $articulo);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $numeroDeFila, $descripcion);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7, $numeroDeFila, $existencia);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(8, $numeroDeFila, $comprometido);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(9, $numeroDeFila, $inventario);
    //$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(8, $numeroDeFila, $diferencia);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(10, $numeroDeFila, '=G' . $numeroDeFila . '-   E' . $numeroDeFila . '-F' . $numeroDeFila);

    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(11, $numeroDeFila, $pesoneto);
    //$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(10, $numeroDeFila, $pesounitario);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, $numeroDeFila, '=I' . $numeroDeFila . '/E' . $numeroDeFila);

    //$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(11, $numeroDeFila, $pesoinventario);
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(13, $numeroDeFila, '=J' . $numeroDeFila . '*(G' . $numeroDeFila . '-F' . $numeroDeFila . ')');
    $hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(14, $numeroDeFila, $uninventarioadas);

    // Incrementa los totales
    $totalExistenciaSucursal += $existencia;
    $subtotalExistenciaSucursal += $existencia;

    $totalExistenciadeposito += $existencia;
    $subtotalExistenciadeposito += $existencia;

    $totalExistencialinea += $existencia;
    $subtotalExistencialinea += $existencia;

    $totalExistenciaGrupo += $existencia;
    $subtotalExistenciaGrupo += $existencia;

    $totalExistenciasubgrupo += $existencia;
    $subtotalExistenciasubgrupo += $existencia;

    $totalExistenciaGeneral += $existencia;

    // Incrementa el número de fila
    $numeroDeFila++;
}

///

// Muestra el total de la última sucursal
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, 'Total x Sucursal:');
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $subtotalExistenciaSucursal);
$numeroDeFila++;

$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, 'Total x Deposito:');
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $subtotalExistenciadeposito);
$numeroDeFila++;

$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, 'Total x Linea:');
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $subtotalExistencialinea);
$numeroDeFila++;

// Muestra el total del último grupo
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, 'Total x Grupo:');
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $subtotalExistenciaGrupo);
$numeroDeFila++;

// Muestra el total del último grupo
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, 'Total x Sub Grupo:');
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $subtotalExistenciasubgrupo);
$numeroDeFila++;

// Muestra el total general
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $numeroDeFila, 'Total General:');
$hojaDeProductos->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $numeroDeFila, $totalExistenciaGeneral);

// Configurar el pie de página con el total general
$pieDePagina = '&LTotal General: ' . $totalExistenciaGeneral . '&RPage &P of &N';
$hojaDeProductos->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter($pieDePagina);

// Crea el escritor y guarda el documento
$writer = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($documento, 'Xlsx');

// Salva el archivo
$writer->save('php://output');

// Finaliza la ejecución del script
exit;
```